# Google Maps with Cordova - Grey Display

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ripple

I have a tough problem to fix, spent some hours and still stucked so I need your help now.

I'm developing an application for exchange students using cordova and Ripple emulator. I simply want to display a map with Google Maps API.

But I have always a grey background event if the styles buttons and google footer are loaded and displayed as shown below :

[Image of my Grey problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whPMf.png)

When I first load my page I have really quickly an image of australia (and then uluru which correspond to the code following) but then the google frame is loaded and grey screen take place again.

To prevent to get this solution, yes I allow every links in my Content Security Policy.

[Image of my Content Security Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZazTQ.png)

Here is the code of my html page for the map (i use angularJS) :

```html
<section class="panel" ng-controller="MapController">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panelFilters"></div>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCirwIL6S55w7cmDLhxo3exIsjn9DwPVtc&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <script>
      function initMap() {

        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
        map.refresh();
      }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</section>
```

And then here the code of my MapController that I call in my html page :

```js
function MapController($scope){
 var isOpen = false;
 var map = document.getElementById('map');

 $(".header").click(function(){

  if(!isOpen){
   $('.header').empty().append("Search filters");
   isOpen = true;
  }else{
   $('.header').empty().append("||");
   isOpen = false;
  }
  
  $(".panelFilters").slideToggle();
 })

 $(window).resize(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        console.log("resized");
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

I absolutely don't know if the problem is related to my code, to ripple or to cordova. Every tip and help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: try  <div id="map"  style="width; 300px; height: 300px;>

Comment: what's the point of this ? Except changing the size that is quite useless no ?

Comment: the point is simple  ... If you don't assign  a real dimension  to you map div  .. then you have a grey display ... .. if you want you can try ,,  could be the problem is also another .. but this is a know cause of this problem ...if you do not like you can ignore my suggestion

Comment: Know i didn't wanted to be offensive, but it's one of the first thing I done and the result is still the same !

Comment: Your map is visible when you launch the application  ..or is in a hidden tab?

Comment: there is an image of australia, without any google maps frame, then the frame appear with the logo at the bottom... and grey background replace the image

Comment: idk if you already checked the image i posted

Comment: have you checked  if there are error in browser  console ..?

Comment: Just one error, roboto fonts can't be load because of the CSP, that's it ...

Comment: No  i don't think  is the fonts  loading the problem .. could be your refresh()  and or map controller() ... (try comment this part just for debug) the maps  should be displayed just using the initMap function

Comment: done, and nothing change

Comment: the refresh was an error, but useless then i removed it